# multiple forms in one page and data should be stored in different tables

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am working on laravel project and came across one requirement.

I have to make an invoice page.

Where we can select client (list will be pulled from database) and project (list will be pulled from database), we have to enter some other details also such as invoice no. In the same page we should be able to enter multiple rows for item name, description, quantity, price, total and currency.

Later we need to pull all this rows data and calculate total amount based on no of rows added.

Below goes my code.

invoices/create:

```
<div class="container">
        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> 'invoiceController@store']) !!} 
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />  
        {{ csrf_token() }}
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1 class="title">Create invoice</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">  
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Invoice details*
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('client', 'Select client:') !!}
                                {!!Form::select('client', [''=>'Choose options']+$client_list,null , array('class'=>'form-control','required' => 'required'))!!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('project', 'Select project:') !!}
                                {!!Form::select('project', [''=>'Choose options']+$project_list,null , array('class'=>'form-control','required' => 'required'))!!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('Idate', 'Invoice date:') !!}
                                    {!! Form::date('Idate',\Carbon\Carbon::now(), null, array('class'=>'form-control','required' => 'required'))!!}
                            </div>   

                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('password', 'PDF password(optional):') !!}
                                    {!! Form::password('password', null, array('class'=>'form-control','required' => 'required'))!!}
                            </div> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Invoice details*
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('invoice_no', 'Draft invoice No:') !!}
                                    {!! Form::number('invoice_no', null, array('class'=>'form-control','required' => 'required'))!!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('p_no', 'PDF no:') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('p_no', null, array('class'=>'form-control','required' => 'required'))!!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8">  
                    {{-- <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Tax details*
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('amount', 'Amount') !!}
                                    {!! Form::number('amount', null, array('class'=>'form-control','required' => 'required'))!!}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('currency', 'Currency:') !!}
                                    {!! Form::Select('currency', ['$' => '$', 'inr' => 'inr'], array('class'=>'form-control','required' => 'required'))!!}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::label('tax_id', 'Tax Rate:') !!}
                                    {{-- {!! Form::Select('tax_id[]', ['NY (4.00%)' => 'NY (4/.00%)', 'VA (5.00%)' => 'VA (5.00%)', 'PA (6.00%)' => 'PA (6.00%)', 'NV (6.85%)' => 'NV (6.85%)', 'NJ (7.00%)' => 'NJ (7.00%)', 'CA (8.25%)' => 'CA (8.25%)'],null, array('class'=>'form-control','multiple' => true,'data-placeholder' => 'Click here to choose')!!} --}}
                                    {{-- {{ Form::select('tax_id[]',['NY (4.00%)' => 'NY (4/.00%)', 'VA (5.00%)' => 'VA (5.00%)', 'PA (6.00%)' => 'PA (6.00%)', 'NV (6.85%)' => 'NV (6.85%)', 'NJ (7.00%)' => 'NJ (7.00%)', 'CA (8.25%)' => 'CA (8.25%)'],null,array('multiple'=>true,'class'=>'form-control','required' => 'required')) }}

                            </div>
                        </div> --}}

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div align="right" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                                <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add</button>
                            </div>
                            <form method="post" id="user_form">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="user_data">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Item</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                        <th>Currency</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                {{-- <div align="center">
                                    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-primary" value="Insert" />
                                </div> --}}
                            </form>
                            <div style="background-color:black;color:white;opacity: 0.8" class="align-items-center" id="user_dialog" title="Add Data">
                                <div class="container ">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6" id="formData">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Item:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="item_name" id="item_name" class="form-control" required/>
                                            <span id="error_item_name" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Description:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="form-control" required/>
                                            <span id="error_description" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Quantity:</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control" required/>
                                            <span id="error_quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Price:</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" required/>
                                            <span id="error_price" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Total:</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="total" id="total" class="form-control" required/>
                                            <span id="error_total" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Currency:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="Currency_item" id="Currency_item" class="form-control" required/>
                                            <span id="error_currency" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="row_id" id="hidden_row_id" />
                                            <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="action_alert" title="Action">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::submit('Create invoice', ['class'=>'btn btn-default btn-block submit_btn']) !!}
            </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
  </div>
```

jquery - It consist code for adding multiple rows. We can click 'add' button and the dialog box will appear to enter item name, description, quantity, price, total and currency. I am sending this data to invoice create page.

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $('#user_dialog').dialog({

    autoOpen:false,
    width:600,
    height:'auto',
    modal: true,
    resizable: true,
  });

  $( "#user_dialog" ).dialog({
    show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 },
    classes: {
          "ui-dialog": "highlight"
        }
  });


  $('#add').click(function(){

    $('#user_dialog').dialog('option','title','Add Data');
    $('#item_name').val('');
    $('#description').val('');
    $('#quantity').val('');
    $('#price').val('');
    $('#total').val('');
    $('#Currency_item').val('');

    $('#error_item_name').text('');
    $('#error_description').text('');
    $('#error_quantity').text('');
    $('#error_price').text('');
    $('#error_total').text('');
    $('#error_currency').text('');

    $('#item_name').css('border-color','');
    $('#description').css('border-color','');
    $('#quantity').css('border-color','');
    $('#price').css('border-color','');
    $('#total').css('border-color','');
    $('#Currency_item').css('border-color','');

    $('#save').text('Save');

    $('#user_dialog').dialog('open');

    $('#save').click(function(){

      var item_name = '';
      var description = '';
      var quantity = '';
      var price = '';
      var total = '';
      var Currency_item = '';

      var error_item_name = '';
      var error_description = '';
      var error_quantity = '';
      var error_price = '';
      var error_total = '';
      var error_currency = '';

      if($('#item_name').val() == '')
      {
        error_item_name = 'Please specify item / task';
      $('#error_item_name').text(error_item_name);
      $('#item_name').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
      item_name = '';
      }
      else
      {
        error_item_name = '';
      $('#error_item_name').text(error_item_name);
      $('#item_name').css('border-color', '');
      item_name = $('#item_name').val();
      } 

      if($('#description').val() == '')
      {
        error_description = 'Please provide description';
      $('#error_description').text(error_description);
      $('#description').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
      description = '';
      }
      else
      {
        error_description = '';
      $('#error_description').text(error_description);
      $('#description').css('border-color', '');
      description = $('#description').val();
      } 

      if($('#quantity').val() == '')
      {
        error_quantity = 'Please enter quantity ';
      $('#error_quantity').text(error_quantity);
      $('#quantity').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
      quantity = '';
      }
      else
      {
        error_quantity = '';
      $('#error_quantity').text(error_quantity);
      $('#quantity').css('border-color', '');
      quantity = $('#quantity').val();
      } 

      if($('#price').val() == '')
      {
        error_price = 'Please enter amount';
      $('#error_price').text(error_price);
      $('#price').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
      price = '';
      }
      else
      {
        error_price = '';
      $('#error_price').text(error_price);
      $('#price').css('border-color', '');
      price = $('#price').val();
      } 

      if($('#total').val() == '')
      {
        error_total = 'Total Amount';
      $('#error_total').text(error_total);
      $('#total').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
      total = '';
      }
      else
      {
        error_total = '';
      $('#error_total').text(error_total);
      $('#total').css('border-color', '');
      total = $('#total').val();
      } 

      if($('#Currency_item').val() == '')
      {
        error_currency = 'Currency is required';
      $('#error_currency').text(error_currency);
      $('#Currency_item').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
      Currency_item = '';
      }
      else
      {
        error_total = '';
      $('#error_currency').text(error_currency);
      $('#Currency_item').css('border-color', '');
      Currency_item = $('#Currency_item').val();
      } 

      if(error_item_name != '' || error_description != '' || error_price != '' || error_quantity != '' || error_total != '' || error_currency != '')
      {
      return false;
      }
      else
      {
        if($('#save').text() == 'Save')
          {
            count = count + 1;
            output = '<tr id="row_'+count+'">';
            output += '<td>'+item_name+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_item_name[]" id="item_name'+count+'" class="item_name" value="'+item_name+'" /></td>';
            output += '<td>'+description+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_description[]" id="description'+count+'" value="'+description+'" /></td>';
            output += '<td>'+quantity+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity[]" id="quantity'+count+'" value="'+quantity+'" /></td>';
            output += '<td>'+price+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price[]" id="price'+count+'" value="'+price+'" /></td>';
            output += '<td>'+total+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_total[]" id="total'+count+'" value="'+total+'" /></td>';
            output += '<td>'+Currency_item+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_Currency_item[]" id="Currency_item'+count+'" value="'+Currency_item+'" /></td>';
            output += '<td><button type="button" name="view_details" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs view_details" id="'+count+'">View</button></td>';
            output += '<td><button type="button" name="remove_details" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_details" id="'+count+'">Remove</button></td>';
            output += '</tr>';
            $('#user_data').append(output);
            console.log(output);
          }
          else
          {
            var row_id = $('#hidden_row_id').val();
            output = '<td>'+item_name+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_item_name[]" id="item_name'+row_id+'" class="item_name" value="'+item_name+'" /></td>';
            output = '<td>'+description+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_description[]" id="description'+row_id+'" value="'+description+'" /></td>';
            output = '<td>'+quantity+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity[]" id="quantity'+row_id+'" value="'+quantity+'" /></td>';
            output = '<td>'+price+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price[]" id="price'+row_id+'" value="'+price+'" /></td>';
            output = '<td>'+total+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_total[]" id="total'+row_id+'" value="'+total+'" /></td>';
            output = '<td>'+Currency_item+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_Currency_item[]" id="Currency_item'+row_id+'" value="'+Currency_item+'" /></td>';

            $('#row_'+row_id+'').html(output);
          }

          $('#user_dialog').dialog('close');
      }

    });

     $(document).on('click', '.view_details', function(){
      var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
      var item_name = $('#item_name'+row_id+'').val();
      var description = $('#description'+row_id+'').val();
      var quantity = $('#quantity'+row_id+'').val();
      var price = $('#price'+row_id+'').val();
      var total = $('#total'+row_id+'').val();
      var Currency = $('#Currency'+row_id+'').val();

      $('#item_name').val(first_name);
      $('#description').val(last_name);
      $('#quantity').val(quantity);
      $('#price').val(price);
      $('#total').val(total);
      $('#Currency').val(Currency);

      $('#save').text('Edit');
      $('#hidden_row_id').val(row_id);
      $('#user_dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Edit Data');
      $('#user_dialog').dialog('open');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove_details', function(){
      var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this row data?"))
      {
      $('#row_'+row_id+'').remove();
      }
      else
      {
      return false;
      }
    });

     $('#action_alert').dialog({
      autoOpen:false
    });

    $('#submit_btn').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var count_data = 0;

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('#formData input').each(function(){
      count_data = count_data + 1;
    });

    if(count_data > 0)
    {
    var form_data = $('#formData input').serialize();

    console.log(form_data);

      $.ajax({
        url:"create",
        method:"POST",
        data:$('#formData input').serialize(),
        success:function(data)
        {
        $('#user_data').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        $('#action_alert').html('<p>Data Inserted Successfully</p>');
        $('#action_alert').dialog('open');
        }
      })
    }
    else
    {
      $('#action_alert').html('<p>Please Add atleast one data</p>');
      $('#action_alert').dialog('open');
    }
  });

  });
});
```

invoiceController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $clients = Client::all(['id', 'name']);
        $client_list = array();

        foreach ($clients as $client) {
            $client_list[$client->id] = $client->name;
        }

        $projects = Project::all(['id', 'p_name']);
        $project_list = array();

        foreach ($projects as $project) {
            $project_list[$project->id] = $project->p_name;
        }

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'client' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'project' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'Idate' => 'required',
            'invoice_no' => 'required',
            'p_no' => 'required',
            'amount' => 'required',
            'currency' => 'required',
            'tax_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        // if ($validator->fails()) {
        //     return redirect('post/create')->withErrors($validator)>withInput();
        // }

        $invoices_row = new invoices_row;
        $invoices_row->item_name = $request['item_name'];
        $invoices_row->description = $request['description'];
        $invoices_row->quantity = $request['quantity'];
        $invoices_row->price = $request['price'];
        $invoices_row->total = $request['total'];
        $invoices_row->currency = $request['currency'];
        $invoices_row->save();

        $invoices = new Invoice;

        $client_name = $request['client'];
        $invoices->client = $client_list[$client_name];

        $project_name = $request['project'];
        $invoices->project = $project_list[$project_name];

        $invoices->Idate = $request['Idate'];
        $invoices->password = $request['password'];
        $invoices->invoice_no = $request['invoice_no'];
        $invoices->p_no = $request['p_no'];
        $invoices->amount = $request['amount'];
        $invoices->currency = $request['currency'];
        $invoices->tax_id = $request['tax_id'];
        $invoices->save();



        return redirect('/invoices');
    }
```

This code is not working and when I click submit button, nothing happens. Please, can anyone help me with this?